# Deviding an odd number into two separate whole numbers

Tags: vba, case

I have the following code. In the last `elseIF`I am struggeling with a formule. See the code here:

```
Select Case GroepAanwezig
        Case 1
              If klas = "T1A2" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1A2 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT1A2
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T2A2" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2A2 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT2A2
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T2A3A" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2A3A & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT2A3A
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T2A3B" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2A3B & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT2A3B
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T2A4" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2A4 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT2A4
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T3A3" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT3A3 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT3A3
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T3A4" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT3A4 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT3A4
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T4A4" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT4A4 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT4A4
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T1A9A" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1A9A & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT1A9A
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T1A9B" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1A9B & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT1A9B
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T1A9C" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1A9C & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT1A9C
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T1K9" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1K9 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT1K9
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T2K3" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2K3 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT2K3
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T2K4" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2K4 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT2K4
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T1G4A" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1G4A & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT1G4A
              ElseIf klas = "T1G4B" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1G4B & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT1G4B
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T2G4" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2G4 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT2G4
              ElseIf klas = "T3G4" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT3G4 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT3G4
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T1E3" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1E3 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT1E3
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T1E4" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1E4 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT1E4
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T2E3" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2E3 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT2E3
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T2E4" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2E4 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT2E4
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T3E3" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT3E3 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT3E3
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T3E4" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT3E4 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT3E4
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T4E4" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT4E4 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = nT4E4
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              End If

        Case 2

             If klas = "T1A2" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1A2 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT1A2 / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T2A2" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2A2 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT2A2 / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T2A3A" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2A3A & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT2A3A / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T2A3B" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2A3B & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT2A3B / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T2A4" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2A4 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT2A4 / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T3A3" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT3A3 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT3A3 / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T3A4" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT3A4 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT3A4 / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T4A4" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT4A4 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT4A4 / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T1A9A" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1A9A & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT1A9A / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T1A9B" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1A9B & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT1A9B / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T1A9C" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1A9C & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT1A9C / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T1K9" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1K9 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT1K9 / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T2K3" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2K3 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT2K3 / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T2K4" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2K4 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT2K4 / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T1G4A" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1G4A & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT1G4A / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T1G4B" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1G4B & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT1G4B / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T2G4" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2G4 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT2G4 / GroepAanwezig)
                    sifir = 0

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T3G4" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT3G4 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT3G4 / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T1E3" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1E3 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT1E3 / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T1E4" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1E4 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT1E4 / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T2E3" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2E3 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT2E3 / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T2E4" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2E4 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT2E4 / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T3E3" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT3E3 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT3E3 / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T3E4" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT3E4 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT3E4 / GroepAanwezig)

                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
              ElseIf klas = "T4E4" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT4E4 & " ) "
                    slbstdperklas = Int(nT4E4 / GroepAanwezig)


                    rest = nT4E4 - slbstdperklas


                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = rest
              End If

        End Select
```

The `Case 1` functions great, have no problems. For `Case 2` I keep on struggeling with an odd number. How can I devide a number for example 31 into 15 and 16.

Lets say there is a formule that can solve this, i get stuck with how to use the  first number 15 later the number 16 as separate numbers.
So I get in one cell for

```html
<table border=1><tr><td>T4E4</td><td>15</td></tr><tr><td>T4E4</td><td>16</td></tr></table>
```

I hope I made my question

Comment: The way you do it `slbstdperklas` will be 15 and `rest` will be 16. Are you asking how to put them in different cells?
You should look up how to use dictionaries or collections. It looks like you could get rid of the `If`s altogether.

Comment: any help on how to fix

Comment: How to fix what? You ask how to separate an odd number into two natural numbers but in your code you already do that.

Comment: Also you should move the `.Vlaue = ...` out of the `If ... ElseIf` statements. It will reduce the code and improve readability. (ideally get rid of the `If`s altogether though)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved it, can someone check it out. Is there way to make this code shorter?

```
Dim GroepenCol As New Collection

'GroepenCol.Add nT9N4, "T9N4"
GroepenCol.Add nT1A2, "T1A2"
GroepenCol.Add nT2A2, "T2A2"
GroepenCol.Add nT2A3A, "T2A3A"
GroepenCol.Add nT2A3B, "T2A3B"
GroepenCol.Add nT3A3, "T3A3"
GroepenCol.Add nT3A4, "T3A4"
GroepenCol.Add nT4A4, "T4A4"
GroepenCol.Add nT1A9A, "T1A9A"
GroepenCol.Add nT1A9B, "T1A9B"
GroepenCol.Add nT1A9C, "T1A9C"
GroepenCol.Add nT1K9, "T1K9"
GroepenCol.Add nT2K3, "T2K3"
GroepenCol.Add nT2K4, "T2K4"
GroepenCol.Add nT1G4A, "T1G4A"
GroepenCol.Add nT1G4B, "T1G4B"
GroepenCol.Add nT2G4, "T2G4"
GroepenCol.Add nT3G4, "T3G4"

GroepenCol.Add nT1E3, "T1E3"
GroepenCol.Add nT1E4, "T1E4"
GroepenCol.Add nT2E3, "T2E3"
GroepenCol.Add nT2E4, "T2E4"
GroepenCol.Add nT3E3, "T3E3"
GroepenCol.Add nT3E4, "T3E4"
GroepenCol.Add nT4E4, "T4E4"

lastRtot = Sheets("totaallijst").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row


For r = 1 To lastRtot
    If Sheets("totaallijst").Cells(r, 9).Value = "" Then
      Sheets("totaallijst").Cells(r, 9).Value = Sheets("totaallijst").Cells(r, 8).Value
      Sheets("totaallijst").Cells(r, 8).Value = ""
    End If
Next r


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Activate
lastRow = Sheets("SLB").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row
  For i = 2 To lastRow 'uit de eerste cel in kolom 1 wordt de x klas gezocht over a1:e10 de klas die terugkrijgt is de aantal voorkomende x
    lastCol = Sheets("SLB").Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    'MsgBox lastRow & " i: " & i 'last row 29 i is correct
    For j = 2 To lastCol


        klas = Sheets("SLB").Cells(i, j).Value

        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas

        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(1, 1).Value = "SLB-ers"
        slbers = Sheets("SLB").Cells(i, 1).Value
        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 1).Value = slbers

        rn_slb = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SLB").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row
        GroepAanwezig = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("SLB").Range("B2:D29" & rn_slb), klas)

        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = GroepAanwezig

        Dim arrOutput(2)
        Select Case GroepAanwezig
            Case 1
                  If klas = "T1A2" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1A2 & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT1A2
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T2A2" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2A2 & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT2A2
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T2A3A" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2A3A & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT2A3A
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T2A3B" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2A3B & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT2A3B
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T2A4" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2A4 & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT2A4
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T3A3" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT3A3 & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT3A3
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T3A4" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT3A4 & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT3A4
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T4A4" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT4A4 & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT4A4
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T1A9A" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1A9A & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT1A9A
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T1A9B" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1A9B & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT1A9B
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T1A9C" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1A9C & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT1A9C
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T1K9" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1K9 & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT1K9
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T2K3" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2K3 & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT2K3
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T2K4" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2K4 & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT2K4
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T1G4A" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1G4A & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT1G4A
                  ElseIf klas = "T1G4B" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1G4B & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT1G4B
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T2G4" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2G4 & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT2G4
                  ElseIf klas = "T3G4" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT3G4 & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT3G4
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T1E3" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1E3 & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT1E3
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T1E4" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT1E4 & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT1E4
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T2E3" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2E3 & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT2E3
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T2E4" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT2E4 & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT2E4
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T3E3" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT3E3 & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT3E3
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T3E4" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT3E4 & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT3E4
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  ElseIf klas = "T4E4" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " ( " & nT4E4 & " ) "
                        slbstdperklas = nT4E4
                        Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = slbstdperklas
                  End If

            Case 2
                    arrOutput(0) = Int(GroepenCol(klas) / GroepAanwezig)
                    arrOutput(1) = GroepenCol(klas) - arrOutput(0)
                    arrOutput(2) = 0
               ' ====== ALGO START
                    ' The following calculate the number of times salk appears before the current cell
                    'Depends on the ROWS since you CAN'T use a range which is not continuous with COUNTIF!
                    Select Case i
                        Case 1
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas)
                        Case 2
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B2" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D1"), klas)
                        Case 3
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B3" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D2"), klas)
                        Case 4
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B4" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D3"), klas)
                        Case 5
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B5" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D4"), klas)
                        Case 6
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B6" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D5"), klas)
                        Case 7
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B7" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D6"), klas)
                        Case 8
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B8" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D7"), klas)
                        Case 9
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B9" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D8"), klas)
                        Case 10
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B10" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D9"), klas)
                        Case 11
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B11" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D10"), klas)
                        Case 12
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B12" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D11"), klas)
                        Case 13
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B13" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D12"), klas)
                        Case 14
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B14" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D13"), klas)
                        Case 15
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B15" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D14"), klas)
                        Case 16
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B16" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D15"), klas)
                        Case 17
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B17" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D16"), klas)
                        Case 18
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B18" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D17"), klas)
                        Case 19
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B19" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D18"), klas)
                        Case 20
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B20" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D19"), klas)
                        Case 21
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B21" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D20"), klas)
                        Case 22
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B22" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D21"), klas)
                        Case 23
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B23" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D22"), klas)
                        Case 24
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B24" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D23"), klas)
                        Case 25
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B25" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D24"), klas)
                        Case 26
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B26" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D25"), klas)
                        Case 27
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B27" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D26"), klas)
                        Case 28
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B28" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D27"), klas)
                        Case 29
                            GroepAanwezigCurr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B29" & ":" & Cells(i, j).Address), klas) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("SLB").Range("B1:D28"), klas)

                        Case Else       ' Should not happen
                            MsgBox "Error, out of range"
                    End Select
                    GroepAanwezigCurr = GroepAanwezigCurr - 1    ' Minus 1 because the current cell would be counted
                    ' ===== ALGO END
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, j).Value = klas & " (" & arrOutput(GroepAanwezigCurr) & ")"
                    Sheets("StdntKlas").Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = arrOutput(GroepAanwezigCurr)
                    slbstdperklas = arrOutput(GroepAanwezigCurr)
                  Case Else
                    'MsgBox "Error"
            End Select




    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Use the collection for `Case 1` as well. Use `Range("B"&i ...)` instead of making a case for every `i`. I don't know where you get the `nT...` variables but maybe you can create the collection at that point.

Comment: the nT... is a cell value that I pressive  from a cel from another sheet.

Comment: At some point in your code you set `nT....` to something, right? Create the collection at that point.